# KiCAD: Potential error in designing schematic symbol

Tags: schematics, kicad, symbol, pinout

I received a part of a schematic. It is this one:

[image]

When i received my parts, i saw that the pinout was reversed. 1-8 was on the left side, while 9-16 was on the right side.

At that time, i didn't know that you could declare your pins however you like, and i thought you should comply to the physical package pinout.

So i did my best to try to translate the schematic i received, to the real physical part - reversing the pinouts, while keeping the circuit the same.

This is my attempt to this.

[image]

The people with much experience at this.... Do you think it's good?
I did my best, checked it many times and i think it is the exact same.

I am asking because my pcb does not work, but i do not why. It probably isn't this, because not even the RESET button works (it's an arduino shield).

But i am doing my best to figure out what's wrong, and i am checking everything out.

Those with an experienced eye, could you please take a look and see if the two schematics are the same? I would very much appreciate it.

Thank you very much and have a great year!

Comment: Since the OPA4353EA is a quad op-amp, I would prefer to draw it as four separate op-amps to make the function clear.  Any good CAD program will allow you to have multiple schematic symbols linked to a single PCB footprint.  Even for parts shown as a single block, the pin arrangement on hte schematic symbol will rarely match the pin placement on the actual part.

Comment: Kicad does what Peter Bennett is describing. E.g. the generic 14-pin quad op amp symbol. If there is not already a 16-pin one,  you can easily copy ("Save-As"...) the 14-pin symbol definition and modify it by adding 2 pins and changing the pin numbering where appropriate. . .

Comment: Have you traced out your actual PCB to make sure it matches what you think your schematic is showing?

Comment: Checking the datasheet for pinout is always a good idea with new parts to make sure the pins in the PCB match those of the part (and the functionality is maintained)

Comment: Try to redraw it without crossing any lines, (unless completely unavoidable) with in to out, going from left to right, look for excellent examples to follow